Получение времени в первозданном виде из БД
Пытаюсь сохранить дату и время в базе данных Postgresql. Prisma сохраняет дату как в UTC так и с учетом часового пояса. При сохранении с учетом чалово пояса пытаюсь запросить по api дату из базы и он ее преобразовывает в UTC к +0.
Как сделать чтобы по запросу NestJS не преобразовывал время и выдавал в сохраненном виде.
